EXPO - Configure New Run Script
Run Script which is being configured in the Xcode Directly, is being repalced as the Expo develoment build generated the IOS Folder.
How Should the Run Script configured in Expo
When trying to implement the Firebase crashlytics in expo i was facing issues were the crash is not captured. Upon Investigating further
I came across this documentation from firebase to target the dSYM File (Logs for the crash).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?hl=en&authuser=2&_gl=1*10maonj*_ga*MTY5ODAzODA4OC4xNzM0ODc5MTI3*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTczNTQ4NjY0OC40LjEuMTczNTQ4NjY4Mi4yNi4wLjA.&platform=ios#kotlin
Then I was not able to find any Run Script Configured for the dYSM so i digged deep were i came across another documentation to configure the Run Scripts
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios&authuser=2#set-up-dsym-uploading
This Run Script is being configured in the Xcode Directly. But In Expo Dev Client the Ios Folder is being replaced when running first time or forcing it to rebuild. In this case the Run Script Which i have configured directly from the Xcode is being removed as the IOS folder itself is regenerated.
How should this be configured from the Expo Itself so that this Run Script is always executed if when running development build from Expo
